Critical error when trying to pair from VS 2022 with MacBook Air
On the MacBook Air:
Xcode version: 15.4
On Windows:
Visual Studio 2022 version: 17.10.5
VisualStudio.Mac 1.0
Xamarin 17.10.0.110
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 16.4.0.23
I get the following messages:
Connecting… Checking host configuration for connecting to ‘xxx’ …
Connecting… Checking SSH configuration…
Connecting… Initializing environment…
Once I get the message “Initializing environment,” Visual Studio stops working, and I can’t do anything else until it either closes or returns errors. The strange thing is that this didn’t happen the first time I paired with the Mac, but it started happening the next day.
This error (see image) occurred in some of my attempts to pair with the Mac.

I have tried the solutions proposed in the following links but nothing has worked:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-Pair-to-Mac-since-upgrading-bo/10439082?q=%5BFixed+In%3A+Visual+Studio+2022+version+17.8+Preview+3%5D
Error connecting to mac from visual studio
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194917/visual-studio-pair-to-mac-stuck-on-connecting


Pair-to-Mac does use SSH amongst other things to connect between Windows and your Mac. These methods of connection are subject to (1) remote login being enabled on your mac, (2) firewall rules relaxed, etc. Rather than troubleshooting Pair-to-Mac, you should begin by troubleshooting at the SSH, remote login and resolve any networking, firewall, security issues there first. Once, you've reliably solved SSH issues, try the Pair-to-Mac again.

Finally, the only thing that worked was reinstalling Visual Studio 2022.

You can post your solution to answer and  answer your own question? From the help center
